# RAD GridView with child columns, grouping and aggregate functions

Tags: wpf, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a Rad Grid View that I'm using to display some data and it may or may not contain child rows. I also implemented grouping with aggregate functions. Everything works right until I show the child grids. It throws an Index Out of Bounds Exception after expanding the child rows in this part of the code.

[image]

I also noticed that the columns are doubled when I expand one of the child rows.

Pic 1. Working all right

[image]

Pic 2. Doubled columns after expanding.

[image]

Any ideas if gropuing with child rows is supported? I did not see any example in Telerik's web page.

Comment: Does the sample Hierachy/Self-Reference Hierarchy do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had an error with my code.  Since the grid columns are populated dynamically through the code, I was running the grouping code in the initialization of the children grid.